# powershell invoke-command does not work if I use -computerName

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I want to execute below code in the either local or remote machine whith current user.

```
$BackUpSqlAgentAndRemoveOldbackup = {
    param([string]$AppServer,[string]$SqlInstance,[string]$BackupShare,[string]$alias)

    [Environment]::UserName #I got same user name in all cases.

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo') | Out-Null

    $server = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $SqlInstance

    $backupName = 'SqlAgentJob_' + $SqlInstance + '_' + (Get-Date –format ‘yyyyMMdd_HHmm’) + '_' + $alias + '.sql'
    $backupPath = join-path $BackupShare $backupName

    $oldBackups = Get-ChildItem $backupShare | where { ( $_.name -like 'SqlAgentJob_*.sql' ) }
    $server.JobServer.Jobs.Script() | Out-File -filepath $backupPath
    foreach ( $item in $oldBackups ) { remove-item $item.fullName }
}
```

the @argList is

```
@('hafcapp-1', 'hafcsql-1', '\\Host5FileSrv\Backup\test','auto')
```

I notice that

this one, it works well (no -comupterName and -session)

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $BackUpSqlAgentAndRemoveOldbackup -argumentList $argList
```

this one, it throw execption (I also tried "-session", get same result)

```
Invoke-Command -computerName localhost -ScriptBlock $BackUpSqlAgentAndRemoveOldbackup -argumentList $argList
```

the exception is as below, it seems the it can not access the folder.

```
Cannot find path '\\Host5FileSrv\Backup\test' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\Host5FileSrv\Backup\test:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Script:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

does anyone know how can I do if I want to add computerName or session?
(notes:[Environment]::UserName return identical user)

Answer (score 2):

You have run into the double hop problem. Your credentials can be transferred to the next machine (first hop), but no further (second hop). This means that you can't use the credentials of the machine where you are executing Invoke-Command on, the remote machine (localhost) to connect to a file share (\Host5FileSrv\Backup). Even if you use localhost as computername, it is still remoting. A solution could be CredSSP. See [here](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1230) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2009/06/25/9803001.aspx) for more information.

[image: double hop]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a "second hop" remoting problem, and you'll need to configure WinRM on the computers involved to use CredSSP

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309365(v=vs.85).aspx